# Backslashed LaTex symbol name + tab in gedit

Tags: julia, gedit

I've just started reading the [docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/variables/) of Julia and I read this:

*In the Julia REPL and several other Julia editing environments, you can type many Unicode math symbols by typing the backslashed LaTeX symbol name followed by tab. For example, the variable name δ can be entered by typing \delta-tab, or even α̂₂ by \alpha-tab-\hat-tab-_2-tab.*

I was wondering if the same can be done in gedit 3.
If possible, how? What plugin should I add?

Comment: A similar result to what you are looking for can be obtained in gedit by using the [mathwriter ibus table](https://github.com/moebiuscurve/ibus-table-others) (the `ibus-table-mathwriter` package in Fedora).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that currently, there is no support for Julia LaTeX completions in Gedit 3 AFAIK.

## Alternatives

### [Juno IDE](http://junolab.org/)

Installation instructions:

- http://junolab.org/docs/install.html

[image]

### IJulia Notebook

Install [`IJulia`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl):

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl#installation

Start the Jupyter notebook server:

- `$ jupyter notebook`

Alternatively you can try IJulia online here:

- [JuliaBox](https://juliabox.org/) (Google authentication required but environment is persistent and integrated with other services like Google Drive)
- [TryJupyter](https://try.jupyter.org/) (No authentication required but files are not persistent)

Open a new notebook with a Julia kernel and type `\<TAB>` to see the full list of completions, after selecting one type `<TAB>` again:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Sublime Text

You'll need to install **IJulia**, the Sublime Text `Package Control` manager:

- https://packagecontrol.io/installation

And the following Plugins:

- [`IJulia`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/IJulia): An IJulia Frontend for Sublime Text 3
- [`Julia​Completions`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JuliaCompletions): Make all of Julia's UTF-8 autocompletions available in Sublime Text

  1. Open an existing `.jl` file (syntax highlighting will be auto detected) or a new file (press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` then type `julia` and select `Set Syntax: Julia`, alternatively save the new file with a `.jl` extension).
  2. Start typing, ie: `\alpha`, select and press `ENTER` or `TAB`.

[image]

**Note:** I **can't** use the IJulia plugin to run code inside Sublime Text 3 (it was last updated a year ago!) but this is supported by Juno. Eitherway this plugin also provides Julia syntax highlighting and it also lets the `JuliaCompletions` plugin *see* the LaTex completions, which they still **do** work!

Currently most development efforts for a Julia IDE are being concentrated on the Juno IDE based on the Atom editor:

- http://julialang.org/blog/2016/01/atom-work
- http://junolab.org/community

There are also several other Julia IDE efforts, I've seen around, but I'm unaware of their current advance, specifically if they support LaTeX completions.

### Vim

Using [julia-vim](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia-vim):

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia-vim#latex-to-unicode-substitutions

### Emacs

Using [julia-mode](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/contrib/julia-mode.el) from `julia/contrib/julia-mode.el`:

- https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/contrib/julia-mode.el#L734-L3190

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer! What IDE do you advise?

Comment: I recommend you to start with Juno, you can get a bundle with Juno + Julia at the official Julia web site: http://julialang.org/downloads or with JuliaBox, since both are the easiest way to get started with minimal hassle. Personally I use IJulia and Sublime Text or Kate editors + Yakuake/Konsole most of the time, with servers I use Tmux + Vim.